# Halloween Pranks, Fun with Cursors

Tags: customization

How can I make a mouse cursor look like a bug, ant, cockroach, bat or something else scary. (but not so scary that someone would smash the screen).

Comment: Well, there's Halloween theme https://www.gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Halloween+Theme?content=91474 Don't know if it changes the cursor or not, though

Comment: @Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy : Thanks, that is definitely a very Halloweeny Theme, But I am just looking for **creepy** mouse cursors.

Comment: A cursor that wiggles would be a special treat.